# how to remove click preventing?

Tags: jquery

there is my code. when i click any category from my navegation menu it doesn't go to my another page. i want that when i will click on any category it should go to that page properly. Please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        /* Navigation */
        $("#nav a.selectcategory").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#nav ul#main_ul").slideToggle();
        });

        $("#nav ul#main_ul li").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).find("ul").is(':visible')) {                
                $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
            } else {
                $("#nav ul#main_ul li ul").slideUp();
                $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
            }
        });

        /* banner catogory select */
        $("#banner .whitebox a.select_2").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#banner .whitebox .selebox ul").slideToggle("fast");
        });




    });

</script>
```

Comment: By any chance your css has "pointer-events: none;" ??

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `e.preventDefault();` since when this method is called, the default action which is your `click` event of the anchors will not be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The anchors are not navigating because the default action is being prevented.

```
$("#nav a.selectcategory").click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault(); remove this
    $("#nav ul#main_ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: @user3197474 Glad I could help.  If you accept one of the answers you will earn a few rep points!

Answer (score 0):

if u wanna to make animation before loading new page do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        /* Navigation */
        $("#nav a.selectcategory").click(function(e) {
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#nav ul#main_ul").slideToggle("normal",function(){top.location = href;});
        });

        $("#nav ul#main_ul li").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).find("ul").is(':visible')) {                
                $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
            } else {
                $("#nav ul#main_ul li ul").slideUp();
                $(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
            }
        });

        /* banner catogory select */
        $("#banner .whitebox a.select_2").click(function(e) {
            var href = $(this).attr("href")
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#banner .whitebox .selebox ul").slideToggle("fast",function(){top.location = href;});
        });




    });

</script>
```

It will first make animation 'slide' and then load new page.